# add list item with custom text color

Tags: android, arraylist, textcolor

i want my code to add a list item with a the text color GREEN if a certain condition is met, otherwise i just want it to add the item with no specified text color

heres my code:

```
                if (cursor.getString(4).equals("yes")) {
                    achievementList.add(cursor.getString(1)+" (completed)");
                }
                else {
                    achievementList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                }
```

ive tried using setTextColor(Color.GREEN) on the cursor.getString as well as the achievementList.add, and both are throwing errors. whats the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Can you post your logcat errors you are receiving? What type of adapter are you using for your listview?

Comment: i cant even compile, and im using `this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, achievements));` to display the items in the list.

Comment: Well, if you can't compile it eclipse (or whatever IDE you are using) should tell you what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should create your own ArrayAdapter and extend from the default one. Than you should override `getView()` and create, fill and modify the views there.
There you can set the text color of the TextView of your choise.

There are a lot of good tutorials out there, just search for it.